# Ammending Equation so that columns A,B do not have to be adjacent to eachother

Tags: excel, excel-2010, formula, excel-365

I have this formula below which sorts data In columns A and B as shown in the image.

[image]

The formula is:
`=SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>'",,A2:B60)&"</s></t>","//s"),"'","")`.

The problem with this question however is that it requires Columns A and B to be adjacent to each other.

Gary Student provided me with the above and an alternative solution that enables the same affect without the columns being adjacent, but this requires a LET function. For those interested this solution is: `=LET(x,INDEX(A$2:E$22,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(42)/2,0),IF(MOD(SEQUENCE(42),2)=0,5,1)),FILTER(x,x<>""))`.

For whatever reason however my work computer despite having excel 365 does not have the LET function and I am unable to update it.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to amend this formula so that columns A and B don't have to be Adjacent.

Comment: Copy the formula starting with `Filter(..` and replace the `x` with the  `INDEX(...` part.  That is all the LET is doing.

Comment: Sorry, I dont quite understand what you mean.

Comment: `=FILTER(INDEX(A$2:E$22,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(42)/2,0),IF(MOD(SEQUENCE(42),2)=0,5,1)),INDEX(A$2:E$22,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(42)/2,0),IF(MOD(SEQUENCE(42),2)=0,5,1))<>"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you needed columns A and C:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>'",,CHOOSE({1,2},IF(A2:A60="","",A2:A60),C2:C60))&"</s></t>","//s"),"'","")
```

should do it.